# vba function to copy certain value from one workbook to another

Tags: vba, loops, for-loop

I have 2 workbooks. I need copy the row in one workbook only if it contains a certain value from another workbook. Here's my code, it works for the first i=21 and i=22 but tells me there's an error in Cells.Find when I reach i=23.

```
For i = 21 To 35
    Windows("Run Report.xlsm").Activate
    Dim strL3 As String
    strL3 = Sheets("Summary").Range("A" & i).Value
    Workbooks("Ace Survey - Level 1 and level 3 Trending (w Resolution) v3").Activate
    Range("A1").Activate
    Cells.Find(What:=strL3, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    If strL3 = "Call Disconnected" Or strL3 = "Caller Not Present" Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(2, 2).Select
    Else
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 2).Select
    End If
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.Copy
    Windows("Run Report.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Summary").Select
    Range("G" & i).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
Next i
```

Comment: What does "works for the first 2 i's but breaks after that" mean? You forgot to tell us how it "breaks", and forgot to actually ask a question. Please [edit] your question to fix those two things, so someone can try and help you. Thanks.

Comment: It loops through i=21 and i=22 but then on 23, it tells me that theres an error in Cells.Find

Comment: Once again, please [edit] your question (click the link I've posted twice now) to add that information there instead of in the comments. Also, "it tells me that theres an error" is **not** a description of the error - what **exactly** does it tell you?

Answer (score 0):

`Find` returns a `Range` object if something is found, but **Nothing** otherwise. You are attempting to Activate the result of using Find, even if it is Nothing - which will generate an error.

You need to store the result of your `Find` attempt in a `Range` variable, and check for `Nothing`.

```
Dim rngFound As Range

Set rngFound = Range("A1").Find(...)
If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
    ' we found something!
Else
    ' Nothing
End If
```

But, as advised, you should be supplying more details for your question.